# Column not found при подсчете суммы денег за месяц

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

Здравствуйте,  у меня на кнопке простой обработчик, в зависимости от того какой номер месяца мы введем в textfield  нам считает сумму денег за заданный месяц. Вот мой код:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cursova", "root", "root");

        String sql = "SELECT YEAR(endDate) as SalesYear , " +
            "MONTH(endDate) as SalesMonth, " +
            "SUM(price) AS TotalSales " +
            "FROM arend where month(endDate) =? " +
            "GROUP BY YEAR(endDate), MONTH(endDate) " +
            "ORDER BY YEAR(endDate), MONTH(endDate)";


        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, textFieldTest.getText());
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            String year = rs.getString("SalesYear");
            labelMonth.setText(year);


            String month = rs.getString("SalesMonth");
            lblYear.setText(month);

            String result = rs.getString("TotalSales");
            resultLabel.setText(result);
        }


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Но выбивает ошибка:

> column 'endDate' not found

Comment: У вас нет столбца с именем `endDate` в таблице в БД

Comment: @АлексейШиманский есть  , вот http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1465333410/bc222af6/12949442.png

Comment: Возможно, вы не обновили БД после добавления этой колонкиэ

Comment: @M-Misha-M в запросе `SELECT` в перечислении нет упоминания колонки `endData` и `price` также

Comment: @АлексейШиманский извините немного уже путаюсь, что мне сделать надо? , я убрал as ошибка та же. тоесть я не могу писать month(endDate) ??? мне нужно извлекать просто именно месяц

Comment: @M-Misha-M вам надо с помощью `getString` выбирать именно те названия, которые вы указали в выборке, в данном случае это `getString("SalesYear")`, `getString("SalesMonth")` и  `getString("TotalSales")`..... Если бы у вас в выборке было `SELECT endData, price FROM table`, то тогда вы могли бы писать `getString("endDate")`...... то что выбираете в запросе, то и выбираете в ResultSet

Comment: @АлексейШиманский   я сделал так , но теперь ошибка  Column 'SalesYear ' not found.

Comment: @M-Misha-M но вы из запроса `AS` при этом не убирайте) Если есть `AS` - то выбирайте по имени, присвоенное за счет этого. Если он отсутствует, то по имени выбираемого столбца..... без AS это будет аж `YEAR(endDate)`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я обновил свой код , см.выше я as не убирал

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40857/discussion-between-m-misha-m-and--).

Answer (score 1):

У вас в результирующем наборе три столбца `SalesYear`, `SalesMonth` и `TotalSales`, названия которым вы назначаете при помощи ключевого слова `AS`. Однако извлекаете вы `endDate` и `price`, поэтому вам возвращается сообщение о невозможности найти столбец с таким названием. Даже если эти столбцы имеются в исходной таблице, в результирующий набор они не попадают.

Comment: я убрал as ошибка та же (( Я не могу писать Month(endDate) ?

Comment: @M-Misha-M, лучше не убирайте конструкцию AS, она позволяет задавать удобные имена. Лучше добавьте в конструкцию SELECT недостающий столбец endDate, а в место rs.getString("price") используйте rs.getString("TotalSales")

Comment: немного не понял, смотрите я поменял скажем String year = rs.getString("SalesYear ");
             labelMonth.setText(year); но теперь оно говорит что тоже такой не существует, можете плиз обновить свой ответ

Comment: ошибка остается та же column 'SaleYear' not found

Comment: В приведенной вами строке  String year = rs.getString("SalesYear ");  в конце SalesYear есть пробел - это опечатка или в код так же? Если он присутствует в коде, его следует убрать.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Проблема исправлена таким запросом. id_arend здесь ключевое поле.

```
String sql = "SELECT id_arend, YEAR(endDate) as SalesYear, "
          + "MONTH(endDate) as SalesMonth, "
          + "SUM(price) as TotalSales " + 
    "FROM arend where month(endDate) =? " + 
    "GROUP BY YEAR(endDate), MONTH(endDate) " + 
    "ORDER BY YEAR(endDate), MONTH(endDate)";
```

Всем спасибо

Comment: `id_arend здесь ключевое поле.` - а? что? я вот не понял О_о

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это primary key , autoincrement  , я его включил в запрос и всё выводит нормально. я так и не понял почему запрос не отрабатывал без select id_arend